# geometric_shapes package error, assimp/aiScene.h not found

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to set up the full Jade installation on Ubuntu 14.04.3..
I've followed the official instructions to do this
(http://wiki.ros.org/jade/Installation/Source), but have hit something
of a roadblock with the following:

`$./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release`

http://answers.ros.org/question/187358/geometric_shapes-package-fails-to-process-assimpaisceneh-not-found/
The above is similar to my problem but no workaround is given there.

Here's the terminal output showing what happened with geometric_shapes:

```
==> Processing catkin package: 'geometric_shapes'
==> Building with env: '/home/toji/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh'
Makefile exists, skipping explicit cmake invocation...
==> make cmake_check_build_system in '/home/toji/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/geometric_shapes'
==> make -j4 -l4 in '/home/toji/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/geometric_shapes'
[ 14%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/geometric_shapes.dir/src/mesh_operations.cpp.o
/home/toji/ros_catkin_ws/src/geometric_shapes/src/mesh_operations.cpp:54:28: fatal error: assimp/aiScene.h: No such file or directory
 #include <assimp/aiScene.h>
                            ^
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/geometric_shapes.dir/src/mesh_operations.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/geometric_shapes.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
<== Failed to process package 'geometric_shapes': 
  Command '['/home/toji/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh', 'make', '-j4', '-l4']' returned non-zero exit status 2

Reproduce this error by running:
==> cd /home/toji/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/geometric_shapes && /home/toji/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh make -j4 -l4

Command failed, exiting.
```

I will appreciate any help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225817/geometric_shapes-package-error,-assimp/aiscene.h-not-found/) by [amitoj](https://answers.ros.org/users/25846/amitoj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-02-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-02-04**:
Please include all relevant console text directly in your question. If the pastebin link ever goes away, this question will become useless. Use the *edit* button/link to update your question, and the *Preformatted text* button to format console copy/pastes.

**Comment by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on 2016-02-05**:
*...I've followed the official instructions to do this ( [http://wiki.ros.org/jade/Installation... ), but have...* Have you tried to replace link with this(jade to indigo): http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Source

**Comment by [juanvallejo](https://answers.ros.org/users/26453/juanvallejo/) on 2016-04-01**:
Hi, after running across the same problem, I found that geometric_shapes expects files only present in older versions of assimp. This one worked for me: https://sourceforge.net/projects/assimp/files/assimp-2.0/assimp--2.0.858-sdk.zip/download (cmake . && make && make install)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

geometric_shapes detects ASSIMP incorrectly, but several other projects do it correctly. You can force the detection to work right by doing by including this on the catkin_make command: `-DASSIMP_UNIFIED_HEADER_NAMES=ON` . Mine looked like this: `./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DASSIMP_UNIFIED_HEADER_NAMES=ON`

---

Originally posted by [BrannonKing](https://answers.ros.org/users/27276/brannonking/) with karma: 76 on 2016-06-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@Orhangazi44: I tried installing Indigo and it has been installed successfully. I also tired Jade again and it also installed successfully. Maybe it was some dependency issue.

---

Originally posted by [amitoj](https://answers.ros.org/users/25846/amitoj/) with karma: 11 on 2016-02-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1